# Manhwa where a guy is summoned to another world, dies there, and goes back to his original world where 40 years have passed

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I saw this on YouTube but there was no name to it. In this manhwa, a guy is summoned to another world, then executed after defeating the Demon Lord, and is then reincarnated back to his original world where 40 years have passed.

Comment: Do you still have the youtube link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3_o-svGtkM&t=1s

Comment: It looks like the youtube uploader has since added the name in the comments: The Savior «Messiah» ~The Former Hero Who Saved Another World Beats The Real World Full Of Monsters~

Answer (score 4):

The original uploader of the youtube video mentioned in the original post has stated that this is *[Messiah: Isekai wo Sukutta Moto Yuusha ga Mamono no Afureru Genjitsu Sekai wo Musou suru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/messiah-isekai-wo-sukutta-moto-yuusha-ga-mamono-no-afureru-genjitsu-sekai-wo-musou-suru)* or *The Savior «Messiah» ~The Former Hero Who Saved Another World Beats The Real World Full Of Monsters~*.

> The "former" savior, Takeru Yamato, **was summoned to another world and executed because of his strength**. When he wakes up, he finds himself in Japan, where he spent time before being summoned. However, in the city, demons appearing from "gates" rampage, and those called hunters fight using magic. Returning from another world, Takeru decides to hide his powers and live, but...

The synopsis covers the summoning to another world and being executed; the first chapter includes the detail of him waking up in Japan, 40 years later.

[image]